# What is classobject in python is it same as class name?

Tags: python, class

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Object reference:', id(self))
        print('Class object reference', id(Test))


t = Test()
```

Object reference: `2170838573008`

Class object reference: `2170806511808`

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same as class name. Everything is an object in Python. Classes are, and their instances, too. Even modules, and functions, just everything.

Answer (score 1):

Class Name is not same as class object. When you create an instance of class that time you create an object for that class. In your case `t` is a  Object of class Test.

Almost everything is object in python. So as your class is a type of object.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
       print('Object reference:',id(self))
       print('Class object reference',id(Test))


t = Test()  // Here t is object of class Test.
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `class` keyword, you are actually creating an instance of type `type`. Classes are instances themselves.

```
class Test:
    pass

print(isinstance(Test, type))  # True
print(type(Test))              # <class 'type'>
```

here, `Test` is just a label in your global namespace, which points to this instance you have created.

Now when you call your class, here `Test`, you are creating an instance of it. `self` inside your class, points to this object (instances of your class).